# convert vb.net to python

Tags: python, vb.net, converters

hello guys i'm wondering if i can convert `vb.net` codes to `python` ?!

i have this code 
`VB.net`

```
dim t as new threading.thread( adressof x,100)
t.start

sub x
do work
end sub
```

i guess it's like

```
def thread(self):
    t = threading.thread(adressof)
    self.x()
def x(self):
    pass
```

so there any converter ? it would be so nice because i got source code for program in vb.net and as you know it's work on only Windows and i want to make it work in Linux so i need Vb to python converter .. thanks a lot guys

Comment: You should accept some of your previous questions...

Comment: [AddressOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx) is a VB operator, so you cannot just literally copy it to Python.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no converter.  They are wildly different languages and VB.NET relies on the .NET framework to function, which Python doesn't.

If you need to get your .NET program working under Linux, you would be much better off utilizing [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com).

Answer (score 1):

There is Visual Basic -> Python translator called [vb2py](http://vb2py.sourceforge.net/), but it hasn't been updated in several years. I'm currently working on a tool called [universal-transpiler](https://github.com/jarble/universal-transpiler) that translates a subset of VB.NET into several other languages, including Python.

Answer (score 0):

Here there are two converters:

http://vb2py.sourceforge.net/

https://www.digitalcoding.com/tools/vb-csharp-to-python-code-converter.html